# Как сделать так, чтобы блоки не ехали?

Tags: html, css

Есть скрытый контент, который появляется в блоке при ховере на родителя. Так же есть некоторый padding который тоже появляется при наведении. Вследствие чего, сдвигаются другие блоки. Как сделать так, чтобы они не уезжали? Скрин ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример одного блока:

```css
.content .hides {
 display: none;
}
.hides {
 position: relative;
}
.hides .fa-shopping-basket {
 background-color: #f15927;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-left: 23px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.itempos {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.hides:hover {
 display: block;
}
.itempos:hover .hides {
display: block;
}
.itempos:hover {
 border: 3px solid blue;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}
.itempos:hover .itemcont {
 padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 itempos">
  <div class="itemcont">
    <div class="image">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/pos1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <a href="" class="name">Диск сцепления ClutchNet (6-ти лепестковая металлокерамика с демпфером)</a>
    <a href="" class="category">Трансмиссия </a>
    <div class="price">8 600 руб. <span>9900 руб.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="hides">
      <a class="podr" href="">Подробнее</a>
      <a class="crt" href=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Полное руководство по Flexbox](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/#polnoerukovodstvopoflexbox)

Comment: Использовал    
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
, уже лучше, но всё равно вместо одного элемента вниз сдвигается вся строка. Можно ли как-то вообще не сдвигать их?

Comment: Ну или `.itempos:nth-child(6n+1) { clear: left; }`, если не хотите заморачиваться с **flexbox**. [Псевдокласс :nth-child](https://webref.ru/css/nth-child)

Comment: вы хотите чтобы верхний элемент перекрывал нижний?

Comment: При наведении - да.

Comment: Не подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
}
body {
  padding: 15px;
}
.title {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.entry-list {
  margin: 0 -10px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 330px;
  list-style: none;
}
.entry-list_i {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 33%;
}
.entry {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.entry_title {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.entry_hidden {
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-top: none;
}
.entry:hover {
  z-index: 10;
  border-color: #66aacc;
}
.entry:hover .entry_hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 class="title">Item List</h1>
  <ul class="entry-list">
    <li class="entry-list_i">
      <article class="entry">
        <h2 class="entry_title">Item #1</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="entry_hidden">
          <p>Hidden block</p>
          <a href="#">Hidden link</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="entry-list_i">
      <article class="entry">
        <h2 class="entry_title">Item #2</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="entry_hidden">
          <p>Hidden block</p>
          <a href="#">Hidden link</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="entry-list_i">
      <article class="entry">
        <h2 class="entry_title">Item #3</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="entry_hidden">
          <p>Hidden block</p>
          <a href="#">Hidden link</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="entry-list_i">
      <article class="entry">
        <h2 class="entry_title">Item #4</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="entry_hidden">
          <p>Hidden block</p>
          <a href="#">Hidden link</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="entry-list_i">
      <article class="entry">
        <h2 class="entry_title">Item #5</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="entry_hidden">
          <p>Hidden block</p>
          <a href="#">Hidden link</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="entry-list_i">
      <article class="entry">
        <h2 class="entry_title">Item #6</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="entry_hidden">
          <p>Hidden block</p>
          <a href="#">Hidden link</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="entry-list_i">
      <article class="entry">
        <h2 class="entry_title">Item #7</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div class="entry_hidden">
          <p>Hidden block</p>
          <a href="#">Hidden link</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Очевидно объединять каждый ряд блоков в отдельный блок-контейнер. В любом другом случае все блоки будут сами за себя.
Или сделать всем блокам абсолютное позиционирование, тогда они не будут сдвигаться со своих мест.
В любом случае, это задача не для css.